# Find the maximum absolute interpolation error

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Let the polynomial $x^4$ be approximated by a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$ which interpolates it at $x=-1,0,1$. Find the maximum absolute interpolation error in the interval [-1,1]

Attempt: Error $\leq (x-x_0)(x-x_1) \cdots (x-x_n) \frac {f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}$ for some c in the interval.

Now, $f^4=4!$ and the maximum value of $x(x+1)(x-1)$ is $0.38$ for $x=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}$ so my answer is $0.38$. however, the answer is given as the range (-0.1,0.1). Please help!

Comment: Your $n$ is not 4, it is 2.

Comment: That said, the given answer also makes no sense, since they asked for the maximum absolute error (or more likely for a bound on that), which should just be a single positive number. Specifically it should be something like $\left ( \max_{c \in [-1,1]} 24|c| \right ) \max_{x \in [-1,1]} |x(x+1)(x-1)|$.